# how to read local json file using objective-c

Tags: objective-c

I am new to iOS, please help me how can I read a local `JSON` file using objective-c

```
SBJSON *parser = [[SBJSON alloc] init];

NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"auth_request" ofType:@"json"];


NSError *error = nil;

NSData *JSONData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath options:NSDataReadingMappedIfSafe error:&error];
NSString *json_string = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:JSONData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];



NSArray *statuses = [parser objectWithString:json_string error:nil];



for (NSDictionary *status in statuses) {


    NSLog(@"%@ - %@", [status objectForKey:@"loginId"], [status objectForKey:@"secret"]);
}
```

Comment: First thing to learn, it doesn't matter that you are using `xcode` you could be doing this in a text editor and it would still be the same.

Comment: `NSArray* statuses = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectFromData:JSONData options:0 error:&error];` (where `error` is the usual NSError object).

Answer (score -1):

Just Add 
   NSArray *tempArray = [json_string JSONVALUE] 
in the place of 
   NSArray *statuses = [parser objectWithString:json_string error:nil];

Don't forget to import

Comment: which file i have to import

Comment: Don't start a newbie on a 3rd-party JSON library.  He should be using Apple's NSJSONSerialization unless there's a good reason to do otherwise.

Comment: could u please tell me how to parse json file with code or send me some good links

Comment: @user3156748 - I explained how to do it 19 minutes ago.  See my comment below your question.